# What's name of the cognac in the below Armenian photo?

Tags: spirits, cognac

Can anyone please name this type of cognac?

[image]

I drank this once and then found this old photo. I believe it to be Armenian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, its name is Proshyan.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if you don’t receive a better one.

Answer (score 2):

It is without doubt the **Armenian "Proshyan" VSOP cognac**. It is not the ["Proshyan" XO](https://eng.winestyle.ru/products/Proshyan-XO.html) or the ["Proshyan" VS](https://eng.winestyle.ru/products/Proshyan-VS.html). All three are from Armenia.

[image: "Proshyan" VSOP]

["Proshyan" VSOP](https://eng.winestyle.ru/products/Proshyan-VSOP.html)